# PhantomJS seems to be loading pages more than once

Tags: javascript, automation, phantomjs

I am trying to experiment page/navigation automation with PhantomJS. However while attempting to open URL and navigating to other pages I found that pages are loading more than once.

Following is scenarios I tried to search term and navigate to other pages using next buttons. However as shown in logs subsequent pages are opened more than once and it grows exponentially will some blank callback too.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
function pageRequest(url){

    function callback(){
        console.log("pass  ----------------- " );
        page.includeJs("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
            var x = page.evaluate(function() {
                    var ret = null;
                  $("a").each(function(ele, i){
                    // console.log($(i).attr("href"));
                    if($(i).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("next")  != -1){
                        // console.log("Hurray !!");
                        ret  = $(i).attr("href");
                        return $(i).attr("href");
                    }

                  });
                  return ret;

            });
            console.log(x);
            // return;
            if(x){
                page.open("http://torrentz.in" + x, callback);
            }
        });
    }

    var page = require('webpage').create();

    page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
      console.log('Page title is ' + msg);
    };

    page.open(url, callback);
}

pageRequest("http://torrentz.in/search?f=test");

//LOGS
$ phantomjs capture.js 
pass  ----------------- 
/search?f=test&p=1
pass  ----------------- 
/search?f=test&p=2
/search?f=test&p=2
pass  ----------------- 
/search?f=test&p=2
/search?f=test&p=2
/search?f=test&p=2
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
/search?f=test&p=3
/search?f=test&p=3
/search?f=test&p=3
/search?f=test&p=3
/search?f=test&p=3
/search?f=test&p=3
/search?f=test&p=3
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
/search?f=test&p=4
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
pass  ----------------- 
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a new page like this:

```
if(x){
  page = require('webpage').create();
  page.open("http://torrentz.in" + x, callback);
}
```